# How to create an attribute for a custom component in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, gluon

After a few hours work I have managed to understand how to create a custom component using javafx and Gluons Scene Builder.
How does one add a new property for that component which will appear in the scene builder properties menu so that the property value can be entered at design time.

Comment: just add getter and setter for the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass something, most likely an implementation of `Parent`, `Region` or `Pane`. From there you can load the FXML which was generated by whatever you have done in `Scene Builder`.

Example:

```
public class MyComponent extends VBox {
    private final StringProperty foo = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public MyComponent {
        final Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));

        getChildren().add(root);
    }

    public final StringProperty fooProperty() { return foo; }
    public final String getFoo() { return foo.get(); }
    public final void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo.set(foo); }
}
```

This may produce an extra container, one being `MyComponent`, the other being the root node of the FXML. To prevent this, use `FXMLLoader.setRoot()`.

## Update

It seems like you have an extra obstacle - the controller which has the main logic is decoupled with `MyComponent`.

There are many ways to do this:

#### By Reference Passing

You can pass in the reference of `MyComponent` into the controller.

```
public class MyController {
    /* Your controller stuff */

    private MyComponent component;

    public final void setComponent(MyComponent component) {
        // You can bind your controller properties to fooProperty here
    }
}
```

Then when loading the FXML in `MyComponent`, you get the reference of the controller and manually call `setComponent()`.

#### By exposing controller property

This method directly exposes the properties of the controller in `MyComponent`

```
public class MyComponent extends VBox {
    // Other stuff

    private MyController controller;

    public MyComponent {
        // Original stuff

        this.controller = loader.getController();
    }

    public final StringProperty fooProperty() {
        assert controller != null; // If you loaded correctly this assertion should be valid

        return controller.fooProperty();
    }

    public final String getFoo() { return fooProperty().get(); }
    public final void setFoo(String foo) { fooProperty().set(foo); }
}
```

#### Integrating controller into the component

This method simply combines `MyComponent` and `MyController` into a single class. You would need `FXMLLoader.setController(this)`.

The advantage is you have direct access to everything. The bad thing is, some people would say this violates MVC.

Comment: When creating a custom component, it is desirable to use `fx:root` to allow the use of `FXMLLoader#setRoot()`. Your example is not wrong, but it is incorrect.

Comment: @mrmcwolf I did indicate that, I thought?

Comment: That has got me almost there however I don't seem to be able to access the getFoo() method from my controller file which is in the same package any suggestions?

Comment: @TonyWolff Updated.